# SSRS 2012 Report Models

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I am preparing a SSRS 2008 R2 commercial demo for my company, using Report Model to produce a kind of "BO Universe" data model to use with Report Builder, to show how users can produce their own reports by using a data model already created by a developer. I found out that Report Models are deprecated in SSRS 2012, is there any new tool to create a data model to deploy on report server, usable by users to produce reports?

Thanks in advance,
Daniele

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Semantic modeling language (SMDL) report models are deprecated. Although you can you continue to use existing report models as data sources in SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services reports you should consider updating your reports to remove their dependency on report models.

SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services does not include tools for creating or updating report models.

SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) no longer supports report model projects. The Report Model designer is not available in SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services (SSRS). You cannot create new Report Model projects or open existing projects in SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) and you cannot create or update report models. To update report models, you can use SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services or earlier tools. You can continue to use report models as data sources in reports authored in SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services (SSRS) tools such as Report Builder and Report Designer. The query designer that you use to create queries to extract report data from report models continues to be available in SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services.

Sources: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143509.aspx) and (mainly) [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143380.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can try exploring power view.
You can create a tabular model and then explore it via power view.