# How to upgrade report model .smdlproj to work in Visual studio 2012

Tags: reporting-services

I have a reporting model built in VSTS but we need to upgrade our solution to Visual Studio 12. we are having trouble upgrading the SMDL project. Can someone help us how to upgrade report model .smdlproj to work in Visual studio 2012?

Comment: having trouble? What kind of trouble?

Comment: when I tried to open the project .smdlproj in Visual Studio 2012, it says. "Unsupported. This version of Visual Studio does not have the following project types installed or does not support them". I have install SSDT for VS2010, SSDT for VS2012, VS2012 SDK, VS2012 Visualization and Modeling SDK. Any help?

Comment: I got answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778040/ssrs-2012-report-models