# Visual Studio 2012 - Incompatible, the application is not installed. Upgrade won't work

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade a project which previously had its target framework set to v2.0, i'm trying to upgrade it to 4.5.2.
I opened my solution within Visual Studio 2012 and the Conversion Wizard runs, it manages to convert 4/5 projects successfully. One project does not get converted and it say: Projectname (incompatible), THe application is not installed.

After looking into the problem, I think the issue is the fact that the project file is in the smldproj format. I believe smld files are no longer supported in VS2012 and thus I can't get this to upgrade. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can upgrade this to work for v4.5.2 .NET.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS 2012 Report Models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778040/ssrs-2012-report-models)

Comment: I've read that thread various times today while searching for a solution. It doesn't help at all as it's really vague. The answer goes on to say 'To update report models, you can use SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services or earlier tools.' I tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: "To update", as in make changes, not upgrade. You can't upgrade them.

Comment: Does that mean it's just not possible? At all? Surely there has to be some way to get around this. I've tried changing the file extensions and manually converting the files into rptproj and rdl files but it's not going very well.